# git merge branch of branch to master

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging

We are developing since a few months with git and we all are new to git. Now we are developing some functionality in a branch where some things went very wrong -- wrong merges from another branch and not the master, rebases, incorrect reverts and so on. Now I don't want to try to recover the branch because it is too messed up.

My question now is: Is it possible to make a branch from this branch (before it has been messed up) continue the development and then merge the branch (of the branch) to master? Is this a good idea or could this cause any (more) problems? With my current knowledge of git it should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question now is: is it possible to make a branch from this branch (before it has been messed up)

You can do it very easily:

```
git checkout -b <new branch> <SHA-1>
```

Now you will have new branch "starting" as the given SHA-1 as the base for all your work.

> continue the development and then merge the branch (of the branch) to master..

Since that point you working on your branch and you can do whatever you fee like doing with it.

Comment: I was a little bit unclear, i already created a branch from the specific SHA-1 sum. But thank you for your answer. I am a little bit shilly-shally because a few days ago we lost some commits because of incorrect merging and rebasing.

Comment: You might not see the commits in your log but you did not lose them they are still stored in git (assuming no gc was running during this time)

Answer (score 2):

You can always make a local copy of your whole repo and do a "test run" where you try to do the scary merge. If you mess it up the scrap the test copy and try again, worst case scenario. But 100% of the time, the "scary" merge turns out to be much easier than I thought. Linus made git pretty darn foolproof.

At the end of the day though, you can merge in and then leave everything uncomitted at first. Then go through the git status and diffs and make sure it's what you expected. If so then run with it. You can always roll back if you missed something.